# image histogram: IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I tried to run a Python program that plots a histogram for a given image. It behaves as expected, but it yields the following error:

```
axes[k,idx].hist(x=fruit[:, :, i].flat, bins=256, range=(0, 255)
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



raspberry = skimage.io.imread(fname="raspberry.jpg", as_gray=False)
apple = skimage.io.imread(fname="apple.jpg", as_gray=False)
fruits_data = [apple,raspberry]


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4)
ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7 = axes.flatten()
axs = [ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7]
i = 0
k=0
for j in range(0, 6, 4):
    for fruit in fruits_data:
        for idx in range(j,j+4):
          if i < 3:
            axes[k,idx].hist(x=fruit[:, :, i].flat, bins=256, range=(0, 255))
            i += 1
          else :
              i = 0
              axes[k,idx].imshow(fruit)
              k = 1

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong: you are trying to access a value in the `axes` array on position `4` (through the `idx` argument in `axes[k, idx]`), while the array is only `4` long on its `1st` axis (so the highest index is `3`).

P.S. Check your imports, you are importing some stuff twice.